# Find values in certain dates in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need help on creating a query that locates ONLY the IDs that are contained in the years 2009, 2010, 2011 and 2012. Sample data below...

> CONSUMERID DATE
>   ........................ ...........
>   00001222 01-01-2009
>   00001222 01-01-2010
>   00001222 01-01-2011
>   00001222 01-01-2012
>   00001985 01-01-2009
>   00007845 01-01-2009
>   00007845 01-01-2010
>   00009898 01-01-2009
>   00009898 01-01-2010
>   00009898 01-01-2011
>   00009898 01-01-2012

... and the results need to be like below...

> CONSUMERID
>   .........................
>   00001222
>   00009898

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
select ConsumerID
from SomeTable
where YEAR(SomeDate) in (2009, 2010, 2011, 2012)
group by ConsumerID
having COUNT(distinct year(SomeDate)) = 4
```

Comment: This worked! My query was off by the "COUNT(distinct year(SomeDate)) = 4" being in the SELECT keyword rather than the HAVING keyword.